# Take and store only some particular values inside a "while" loop

Tags: python, loops

I am solving some partial differential equation discretizing the time and space, to avoid complexity I avoid this thing and just consider that I solve in an iterative way the problem using a function that I called "computation" . The point is that I want to take (and store in some matrix called "Cn") some values given by "y" of the loop "while", but without take all the values of the iteration in time.

To be precise: I am doing a loop "while" for the time evolution taking some time steep dt. I am runing it from t=1 up to t=100 using dt=0.001. My solution "y" is computed to each time steep. The point is that I want to store "y" at some particular values of the time "t", not at each time steep of the loop, i.e for instance I want to store the values at t=1.0,2.0,3.0,...,100.0 using the values that I compute inside the loop while. But I don't want to store the values of "y" at t=1.001,1.002,1.003 etc

I show you the code that I did

```
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation



# grid in 1D
xmin = 0.0
xmax = 100.0
Nx = 120
dx = (xmax-xmin)/Nx
x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,Nx)
# timing of the numerical simulation
t_initial = 1.0
t_final = 100.0
t = t_initial
dt = 10**(-2)
#initial profile
y = np.exp(-0.5*x**2)
#number of time points to store the numerical solution
dt_solution = 1.0 #time steep to save the numerical data inside the loop while
Nt = int((t_final-t_initial)/dt_solution)




def computation(t,y):
    return np.log(t)+y




Cn = np.zeros((Nt, len(x))) # holds the numerical solution
Cn[0,:] = y #we put the initial y
ite = 0
while t<t_final:


    t += dt #WE MAKE THE TIME STEEP
    ite +=1

    y = computation(t,y)

    #Cn[ite,:] = y #I WANT TO SAVE THE VECTOR Y FOR THE TIMES t THAT I AM INTERESTD, NOT THE ONES GIVEN INSIDE THE LOOP WHILE
```

Someone knows how to do that? I was thinking maybe solve this problem using two loops, but I would like to know if its possible to use some more efficient way. Thanks! (I hope that my question is clear, if not please tell me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). This operator shows the remainder when one number is divided by another. For example:

```
10%2 = 0 # 10 is exactly divisible by 2  
11%2 = 1 # 11 is divisible by 2 with remainder 1
```

We can use this with an if condition within the `while` loop.

```
#...

t = 0
dt=0.001 #timestep for iteration

# set the condition threshold
threshold = dt/10
# choose the step you want to save values at
store_step = 0.1

while t<100:
    t += dt
    y = computation(t,y)
    if (t%store_step<threshold) or (t%store_step>(store_step-threshold)):
       # store y values
       Cn[ite,:] = y
```

**Note** If your timestep is an integer you could use: `if (t%1==0)` as your condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but I have a question, it's working when I want to take t=1.0,2.0,3.0, etc, But what happens if I want take the values for times: 1.1,1.2 , 1.3, 1.4 etc? I don't see how can be generalized using the "threshold" variable that you use

Comment: I have edited the answer to be more general. You just need to change the value of modulo you are taking (in this answer 'store_step')

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `while` loop where you want to save `y`:

```
if int(t % 1) == 0:
    Cn[ite,:] = y
```

So this only saves `y` when `t` is divisible by `1`, i.e., `t` is `1.000, 2.000...`

Likewise, if you have other conditions in which you want to only save `y` under, simply check against that condition in a way that can be computed.  If not, a static `list` or `set` is a viable option as well.